# SharePoint Designer 2010 - Determine if today's date is within x days of a start date column using conditional formatting

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, conditional-formatting

I'm using SPD 2010 and Sharepoint Server 2010.

Using conditional formatting I'm trying to format a list so that if today's date is greater than 3 days past the start date column a cell will turn red.

Comparing two date columns directly (to see if today is after the start date) works well -

ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($thisNode/**@StartDate**)))  < ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(**$Today**)))

But if I add a number it will work in SPD design view, but not on the actual SharePoint site.

ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($thisNode/**@StartDate**))) + ***3*** < ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(**$Today**)))

I tried converting 3 to ticks -> 8,640,000/day and using that value, but that didn't work either (and doesn't work in SPD design view).

I can get the formatting to work if I create a column with a calculated date of "StartDate+3" and then compare that directly, however, it doesn't work if the column is not visible and I would rather not create additional columns.

Any ideas?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following worked for me:

number(ddwrt:FormatDateTime(ddwrt:FormatDate(string($thisNode/@StartDate),1033,1),1033,'yyyyMMdd')+3) <= number(ddwrt:FormatDateTime(ddwrt:FormatDate(string($Today),1033,1),1033,'yyyyMMdd'))

Comment: You should tick to accept this answer to indicate the question is closed (useful to possible late answerers like myself). :)

Comment: Thanks Stuart, I was worried it was a StackOverflow faux pas to accept your own answer.

Comment: Thankfully not, but you don't get the +15 accepted answer bonus unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but this didn't work for me. The second FormatDateTime parameter - 'yyyyMMdd' - kept throwing an error.

This finally worked:

```
number(translate(substring-before(@StartDate,'T'),'-',''))+3 <= number(translate(substring-before($Today,'T'),'-',''))
```