# How do you write SharePoint 2010 conditional formatting for this?

Tags: sharepoint, xpath, formatting, conditional-statements, designer

I am using SPD 2010 and SharePoint Sever 2010.

Using conditional formatting I'm trying to format a list so that if today's date is greater than 30 days before the start date column a cell will turn red.

I've tried several XPath expressions from other Stackoverflow entries but nothing has worked. I'm wondering if I am even adding the XPath expression in the right place: In SPD I am selecting a date from the desired column, choosing "Conditional Formatting", selecting "Format Column", selecting "Advanced" and putting my expressions in the XPath expression textbox.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Basically, XPath works on XML data. So, if you could post your XPath and the corresponding sample XML data (both as formatted code block, not image), anybody with knowledge on XPath & XML can help... otherwise, you got to wait for somebody that know all the tech stack involved (sharepoint, XML, XPath, etc)

Comment: Thank you for responding. Where do I extract the XML data from?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest a non-Xpath approach, but if you're looking to stick with Xpath you should take a look at the answers on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262878/sharepoint-designer-2010-determine-if-todays-date-is-within-x-days-of-a-start).

After struggling with this problem myself, I've taken to using JavaScript for conditional formatting, since it can work with dates (including the current date), numbers, and strings, and it can manipulate HTML pretty easily.

A bit of client side code can automatically:

1. Detect whether a list of conditional formatting rules exists
2. Create the list if necessary
3. Provide an interface for creating new rules (which are stored as list items) that should apply to the current page
4. Loop through all the current page's rules and apply them to any list view web parts detected on the same page

The nicest part of this approach is that I can add the web part to a page and just let the business users configure the formatting to their liking; no need for me to be further involved whenever they want to change something.

I put the combined HTML/CSS/JavaScript in a text file that can be saved to a document library somewhere in my site collection. To then add the conditional formatting to page, I just add a content editor web part to the page and set its "content link" property to be the path to the text file.

The content editor web part then displays a gray "Conditional Formatting" button that the user can click to view and modify the formatting rules, as seen in the screen shot below.

[image]

Here's the conditional formatting code for SharePoint 2010 that I use in my text file:

```html
<div id="_conditional_formatting_link" style="display:none; ">
 <div unselectable="on"  style="display:inline-block; user-select:none; cursor:pointer; padding: 3px; background-color:#9b9b9b; color:white; border:1px solid #888;" onclick="javascript:var rules = document.getElementById('_conditional_formatting'); if(rules.style.display == 'none'){rules.style.display = 'inline-block'}else{rules.style.display = 'none'}">
  Conditional Formatting
 </div>
</div>
<div id="_conditional_formatting" style="display:none;background-color:#dfdfdf; border: 1px solid black; width:95%; max-width:1100px;">
 <a style="border:0px;padding:5px;float:right;" title="Reapply Formatting" href="javascript:getConditions(false);">
  <img style="border:0px;" src="/_layouts/images/staticrefresh.gif"/>
 </a>
<ol id="_conditional_formatting_rules"></ol>
<div style="text-align:right; ">
 <div id="_add_conditional_formatting_rule" unselectable="on" onclick="javascript: Add_Conditional_Formatting();" style="user-select:none; cursor:pointer; padding: 3px; margin: 3px; display:inline-block; background-color:#9b9b9b; border:1px solid #888; color:white;">Add Rule</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
 this.cfl = this.cfl ? this.cfl : new Object(null);
 var conditionalFormattingList = "Conditional Formatting";
 function getConditions(reloadRules) {
  /* if reloadRules, query the conditions list and get all the rules. Otherwise just reapply the ones in memory to the current document. */
  if (typeof reloadRules == "undefined") { reloadRules = true; }
  if (reloadRules) {
   var conditionalFormattingRules = document.getElementById("_conditional_formatting_rules");
   while (conditionalFormattingRules.children.length > 0) { /* Clear out the currently displayed list of rules. */
    conditionalFormattingRules.removeChild(conditionalFormattingRules.children[0]);
   }
   this.cfl.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
   this.cfl.user = cfl.clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
   var list = cfl.clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(conditionalFormattingList);
   var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
   var folder = list.get_rootFolder();
   camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'URL\' /><Value Type=\'Text\'>' + document.location.pathname + '</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Priority\' /><FieldRef Name=\'Name\' /></OrderBy></Query></View>');
   this.cfl.items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
   cfl.clientContext.load(cfl.user);
   cfl.clientContext.load(list, 'EffectiveBasePermissions');
   cfl.clientContext.load(cfl.items);
   cfl.clientContext.load(folder);
  }
  this.cfl.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
   Function.createDelegate(this,
    function () {
     var Me = this.cfl.user.get_title(); 
     if (reloadRules) {
      var baseFormUrl = folder.get_serverRelativeUrl() + "/EditForm.aspx?ID=";
      /* Figure out if the current user has access to create or edit items on the Conditional Formatting list */
      var perms = list.get_effectiveBasePermissions();
      this.cfl.hasEdit = perms.has(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems);
      this.cfl.hasCreate = perms.has(SP.PermissionKind.addListItems);
      /* Fill an array with our formatting rules */
      this.cfl.targets = [];
      var itemEnumerator = this.cfl.items.getEnumerator();
      while (itemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
       var item = itemEnumerator.get_current();
       var targ = new Object(null);
       targ.column = item.get_item("Column");
       targ.comparison = item.get_item("Comparison");
       targ.style = item.get_item("Style");
       targ.scope = item.get_item("Scope");
       targ.type = item.get_item("Type");
       targ.value = item.get_item("Value"); if (targ.value == null) { targ.value = ""; }
       targ.id = item.get_item("ID");
       targ.offset = item.get_item("Offset");
       cfl.targets.push(targ);
      }
     }
     if (!this.cfl.hasCreate) { document.getElementById("_add_conditional_formatting_rule").style.display = "none"; }
     for (var targetIterator = 0, len = cfl.targets.length; targetIterator < len; targetIterator++) {
      var currentTarget = cfl.targets[targetIterator];
      if (reloadRules) {
       var rulelist = document.getElementById("_conditional_formatting_rules");
       var ruletoadd = document.createElement("li");       
       var comparisondisplay = currentTarget.type.indexOf("Field") != -1 ? "value of the <b>" + currentTarget.value + "</b> column" : "<b>'" + currentTarget.value + "'</b>";
       if (currentTarget.type == "Special" || currentTarget.type == "Number") {
        if (currentTarget.value.toString().toLowerCase() == "[me]") { comparisondisplay = "<b>[Me](" + Me + ")</b>"; }
        else { comparisondisplay = "<b>" + currentTarget.value + "</b>"; }
       }
       if (currentTarget.value == "") { comparisondisplay = "<b>(blank)</b>"; }
       if (currentTarget.offset != null) {
        comparisondisplay += "<b>" + (currentTarget.offset < 0 ? " " : " +") + currentTarget.offset + "</b>"
       }
       var editLink = this.cfl.hasEdit ? "<div style='display:inline-block;cursor:pointer;' onclick='SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogOpen(" + '"' + baseFormUrl + currentTarget.id + '&Source=' + document.location.pathname + '"' + ",{},refreshPageConditions); '>" + "<img src='/_layouts/images/EDITITEM.GIF' style='vertical-align:middle;' title='Customize' alt='Customize'/>" + "&nbsp;</div>" : "";
       ruletoadd.innerHTML = editLink + "When <b>" + currentTarget.column + "</b> "
        + currentTarget.comparison + " " + comparisondisplay
        + ", apply {" + (currentTarget.style == null ? "remove all formatting" : "<span style='" + currentTarget.style + "'>" + currentTarget.style + "</span>") + "} to the <b>" + currentTarget.scope + "</b>" + ((currentTarget.scope != "Cell" && currentTarget.scope != "Row") ? " column" : "");
       rulelist.appendChild(ruletoadd);
      }
      var tables = document.querySelectorAll("table.ms-listviewtable"); /* Should get all the list view web parts on the page. */
      var t_i = 0;
      while (t_i < tables.length) {
       var columnIndex = null; /* Index of the column to compare against */
       var valueIndex = null; /* Index of a second column from which to pull the value to compare */
       var styleTargetIndex = null; /* Index of a column to apply formatting to */
       var thisTable = tables[t_i];
       var headings = thisTable.rows[0].cells;
       var h_i = 0;
       while (h_i < headings.length) { /* Check all the column headings... */
        var thisHeading = headings[h_i].querySelector("div:first-child");
        if (thisHeading != null) {
         /* In Internet Explorer, the headings have a DisplayName attribute you can grab. If that's not there, just grab the innerText or textContent */
         var dispname = thisHeading.DisplayName ? thisHeading.DisplayName : (thisHeading.innerText ? thisHeading.innerText : thisHeading.textContent);
         dispname = dispname.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');/* removes leading and trailing whitespace */
         if (currentTarget.scope != "Cell" && currentTarget.scope != "Row") {
          /*If the scope isn't Cell or Row, see if this is the cell to which the formatting should applied */
          if (dispname == currentTarget.scope) { styleTargetIndex = h_i; }
         }
         if (currentTarget.type.indexOf("Field") != -1) {
          /*If the value type is a Field, check to see if this is the field whose value we care about */
          if (dispname == currentTarget.value.toString()) { valueIndex = h_i; }
         }
         if (dispname == currentTarget.column) { columnIndex = h_i; }
        }
        h_i += 1;
       }
       if (columnIndex != null) { /* If we found a matching heading, let's try to apply the rules... */
        var rows = thisTable.rows;
        for (var i = (rows.length > 0 ? 1 : 0) ; i < rows.length; i++) {
         var cells = rows[i].children;
         if (cells.length <= columnIndex) { continue }
         var innerLink = cells[columnIndex].querySelector("a"); /* I want to specifically target links so that we can change their text color if necessary */
         /* Populate valueToEval with the text value of the current cell, or its inner link if it has one */
         var valueToEval = cells[columnIndex].innerText ? (innerLink != null ? innerLink.innerText : cells[columnIndex].innerText) : (innerLink != null ? innerLink.textContent : cells[columnIndex].textContent);
         if (typeof (valueToEval) == "undefined") { valueToEval = "" } /* Treat empties as blanks */
         var listValueToCompareAgainst = null;
         if (valueIndex != null) { /* valueIndex only has a value if we need to grab the comparison value from another column on the list */
          valueLink = cells[valueIndex].querySelector("a");
          listValueToCompareAgainst = cells[valueIndex].innerText ? (valueLink != null ? valueLink.innerText : cells[valueIndex].innerText) : (valueLink != null ? valueLink.textContent : cells[valueIndex].textContent);
         }
         var needsStyling = false;
         switch (currentTarget.type) {
          case "Number":
           if (!isNaN(Number(valueToEval))) {
            valueToEval = +(valueToEval);
           }
           if (!isNaN(Number(currentTarget.value))) {
            currentTarget.value = +(currentTarget.value);
           }
           break;
          case "Date":
           valueToEval = new Date(valueToEval);
           currentTarget.value = new Date(currentTarget.value);
           if (currentTarget.offset != null) {
            currentTarget.value.setDate(currentTarget.value.getDate() + +(currentTarget.offset));
           }
           break;
          case "Text": /* Already covered, bro */ break;
          case "Date Field":
           valueToEval = new Date(valueToEval);
           currentTarget.value = new Date(listValueToCompareAgainst);
           if (currentTarget.offset != null) {
            currentTarget.value.setDate(currentTarget.value.getDate() + +(currentTarget.offset));
           }
           break;
          case "Text Field": currentTarget.value = listValueToCompareAgainst; break;
          case "Number Field":
           if (!isNaN(Number(listValueToCompareAgainst))) {
            currentTarget.value = listValueToCompareAgainst;
            if (currentTarget.offset != null) {
             currentTarget.value += Number(currentTarget.offset);
            }
           }
           if (!isNaN(Number(valueToEval))) {
            valueToEval = Number(valueToEval);
           }
           break;
          case "Special":
           if (currentTarget.value.toLowerCase) {
            if (currentTarget.value.toLowerCase() == "[me]") { currentTarget.value = Me }
            else if (currentTarget.value.toLowerCase().indexOf("[today]") != -1) {
             var dateDifference = Number(currentTarget.value.toLowerCase().replace("[today]", "").replace(" ", "").replace("+", ""));
             currentTarget.value = new Date();
             if (!isNaN(dateDifference)) { currentTarget.value.setDate(currentTarget.value.getDate() + dateDifference); }
             if (currentTarget.offset != null) {
              currentTarget.value.setDate(currentTarget.value.getDate() + Number(currentTarget.offset));
             }
             valueToEval = new Date(valueToEval);
            }
           } else { valueToEval = new Date(valueToEval); }
           break;
         }
         switch (currentTarget.comparison) {
          case "Greater Than or Equal To": needsStyling = (valueToEval >= currentTarget.value); break;
          case "Greater Than": needsStyling = (valueToEval > currentTarget.value); break;
          case "Less Than or Equal To": needsStyling = (valueToEval <= currentTarget.value); break;
          case "Less Than": needsStyling = (valueToEval < currentTarget.value); break;
          case "Equal To": needsStyling = (valueToEval == currentTarget.value); break;
          case "Not Equal To": needsStyling = (valueToEval != currentTarget.value); break;
          case "Contains": needsStyling = (valueToEval.indexOf(currentTarget.value) != -1); break;
          case "Does Not Contain": needsStyling = (valueToEval.indexOf(currentTarget.value) == -1); break;
         }
         if (needsStyling) {
          var links;
          if (currentTarget.scope != "Row") {
           var targetIndex = (styleTargetIndex != null) ? styleTargetIndex : columnIndex;
           cells[targetIndex].setAttribute("style", currentTarget.style);
           links = cells[targetIndex].querySelectorAll("a");

          } else {
           rows[i].setAttribute("style", currentTarget.style);
           for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
            cells[j].setAttribute("style", currentTarget.style);
           }
           links = rows[i].querySelectorAll("a");
          }
          for (var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
           if (links[j].title != "Open Menu") {
            links[j].setAttribute("style", currentTarget.style);
            links[j].style.backgroundColor = "";
           }
           links[j].style.border = "0px";
          }
         }
        }
       }
       t_i += 1;
      }
     }
     document.getElementById("_conditional_formatting_link").style.display = "inline-block";
    }
   ),
   Function.createDelegate(this,
    function (sender, args) { /* There was an error accessing the list. Time to create it! */
     var lci = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
     lci.set_title(conditionalFormattingList);
     lci.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.genericList);
     var condition_list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().add(lci);
     clientContext.load(condition_list);
     var colTitle = condition_list.get_fields().getByTitle("Title");
     colTitle.set_required(false); colTitle.set_hidden(true); colTitle.update();
     condition_list.update();
     var colColumn = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Description=\'The column to compare (must be visible on the page)\' DisplayName=\'Column\' Type=\'Text\'/>', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
     var colComparison = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Description=\'\' Type=\'Choice\' DisplayName=\'Comparison\' Format=\'Dropdown\' FillInChoice=\'FALSE\'><Default>Equal To</Default><CHOICES><CHOICE>Greater Than</CHOICE><CHOICE>Greater Than or Equal To</CHOICE><CHOICE>Equal To</CHOICE><CHOICE>Less Than or Equal To</CHOICE><CHOICE>Less Than</CHOICE><CHOICE>Not Equal To</CHOICE><CHOICE>Contains</CHOICE><CHOICE>Does Not Contain</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
     var colValue = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Description=\'The value or the name of a column to compare against\' DisplayName=\'Value\' Type=\'Text\'/>', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
     var colType = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Description=\'Indicate the type of value you are comparing against. Choose Special if using the [Me] or [Today] placeholders.\' Type=\'Choice\' DisplayName=\'Type\' Format=\'Dropdown\' FillInChoice=\'FALSE\'><Default>Text</Default><CHOICES><CHOICE>Date</CHOICE><CHOICE>Number</CHOICE><CHOICE>Text</CHOICE><CHOICE>Date Field</CHOICE><CHOICE>Number Field</CHOICE><CHOICE>Text Field</CHOICE><CHOICE>Special</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>');
     var colOffset = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Description=\'Optionally specify a number to offset the value by when comparing against a number or date.\' DisplayName=\'Offset\' Type=\'Number\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
     var colStyle = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field NumLines=\'4\' Description=\'The CSS to apply to when the condition is met. Leave blank to remove formatting. Example syntax: background-color:darkred; color:white; font-weight:bold;\' DisplayName=\'Style\' Type=\'Note\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
     var colScope = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Description=\'The scope to which the style should be applied. Choose Row, Cell, or specify a column name.\' Type=\'Choice\' DisplayName=\'Scope\' Format=\'Dropdown\' FillInChoice=\'TRUE\'><Default>Cell</Default><CHOICES><CHOICE>Cell</CHOICE><CHOICE>Row</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
     var colPriority = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Description=\'Priority determines which styles are applied in case of overlapping conditions. Higher numbers are applied later.\' DisplayName=\'Priority\' Type=\'Number\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
     var colUrl = condition_list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Description=\'Page where this rule should be applied\' DisplayName=\'URL\' Type=\'Text\'/>', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
      Function.createDelegate(this, function () { getConditions(); }),
      Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) { document.getElementById("_conditional_formatting").innerHTML = ("An error occcurred while trying to apply conditional formatting to the list for you. Error details: " + args.get_message() + " " + args.get_stackTrace()); document.getElementById("_conditional_formatting_link").style.display = "inline-block"; }));
    }
   ));
 }
 /* This method is called when the Add Rule button is clicked. */
 function Add_Conditional_Formatting() {
  /* Create a new item with only the URL and Priority fields filled out */
  var currUrl = document.location.pathname;
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
  var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
  var newItem = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(conditionalFormattingList).addItem(itemCreateInfo);
  newItem.set_item('URL', currUrl);
  /* Give the new item a priority that will put it at the end of the list. This is kind of a hack since the highest priority is not necessarily the rulecount. */
  newItem.set_item('Priority', document.getElementById("_conditional_formatting_rules").children.length + 1);
  newItem.update();
  clientContext.load(newItem);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
   getConditions(); /* Reload to refresh the rules list after adding the item */
  }), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) { alert(args.get_message()); }));
 }

 /* This method is called when the Edit Item dialog box is closed. It refreshes the page it the item was saved. */
 function refreshPageConditions(result) { if (result != SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) { window.location.replace(document.location.href) } }

 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
  getConditions();
  /* If there are any collapsible sections on the page, keep checking to see whether formatting needs to be reapplied */
  this.cfl.TableRowCount = 0;
  if (document.querySelector("img[alt='expand']") != null) {
   setInterval(function () {
    var tempTableRowCount = document.querySelectorAll("tr").length;
    if (tempTableRowCount != this.cfl.TableRowCount) {
     /* Only reapply formatting if the count of table rows is different than it was previously */
     this.cfl.TableRowCount = tempTableRowCount;
     getConditions(false) /* Passing false reapplies loaded rules without re-querying the SharePoint list */
    }
   }, 1000)
  }
 }, "SP.JS");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm sticking with the XPath route as I feel it would be easier for me to get. I checked out that link in your comment and tried the suggested code and even some variations but I can't seem to get any of the styles to work. I edited my main entry to show the XPath expression that is not working to see if anyone is able to correct it.